# Subquery for each separate row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I've got the query which gets group tasks for specified user_id

```sql
select tasks.id, tasks.title, tasks.description, tasks.task, g.name
from tasks
    join group_task gt on tasks.id = gt.task_id
    join `groups` g on g.id = gt.group_id where gt.group_id in (select g.id from user_group
    join `groups` g on g.id = user_group.group_id where user_group.user_id = 1)
```

i would like to add extra cell for each row which will indicate wether the task is done or not by the user. I came up with such query:

```sql
select count(*) done from user_task_done where task_id = 5 and user_id = 1
```

The question is how do i execute this query for each row (also i need to get current task_id from tasks somehow) and add the result to an exta column called 'done'?

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help.

Comment: I think your query could be simplified.  I would suggest asking a new question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a single field from a subquery as long as it only returns one column and one row

```
select tasks.id, tasks.title, tasks.description, tasks.task, g.name, (select count(*) from user_task_done where task_id = tasks.id and user_id = 1) done
from tasks
    join group_task gt on tasks.id = gt.task_id
    join `groups` g on g.id = gt.group_id where gt.group_id in (select g.id from user_group
    join `groups` g on g.id = user_group.group_id where user_group.user_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use subselects.

```
select count(*) as done 
from user_task_done 
where 
1=1
and task_id in (select task_id from from task) 
and user_id in (select user_id from from users where user_id > 5)
```

In the subselects you can add filters as well.